# Auto change order status from processing to completed in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change every order from woocommerce if the 'PROCESSING' status will automatically be updated to 'COMPLETED'.

I have tried writing the function in functions.php file but I did not succeed.

How can I automatically change the order status from "processing" to "completed" in Woocommerce when I have received payment from the user?

I use this code but it has no effect

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
    function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            return;
        }

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        if( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) 
        {
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
```

Thank's

Comment: when you want to convert processing to completed? At thank you page or do you want to run one cron job?

Comment: The below answer is working for you ?

Comment: @prateik-darji it doesn't work for me. do you have another solution?

Comment: @dipmala when I have received payment from the user

Answer (score 5):

To auto completed orders, you should try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
    function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            return;
        }

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).I have tested the code and its working for me please check screenshot https://prnt.sc/m3zrwp

Comment: hi @developerme, I have added the code but the status is not immediately changed to completed. is there still something wrong? [link](https://prnt.sc/m49es4)

Comment: Did you installed any other plugin ? Its working for me i have tested this code

Comment: does this code only work for payment methods from woocommerce? Because I use another payment method where they only update the status from 'on-hold' to 'processing' when the payment has been completed and then we update one by one to 'completed'.

Comment: which payment method are you using ?

Comment: im using online payment from [midtrans](https://wordpress.org/plugins/midtrans-woocommerce/)

Comment: online means which plugin you are using for payment ?

Comment: im using midtrans, in the plugin Midtrans provides online payment

Answer (score 1):

Use woocommerce_order_status_processing in trigger! woocommerce_thankyou is called only in direct checkout proccess